# XAML Animation : How to animate The user control appearance and disappearance using BLEND

Tags: c#, animation, winrt-xaml, expression-blend, blend

I am working on a Windows 8 Metro app /RT app. I have a specific requirement around a user control.

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="controlMagnifier.MagnifierUsercontrol"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:controlMagnifier"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"

    d:DesignWidth="200">


    <Canvas x:Name="controlCanvas" x:FieldModifier="public"   >
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform>

            </RotateTransform>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>

        <Grid Height="250" Width="176" Canvas.Left="23" Canvas.Top="40" >

                <Border x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="imgBorder" Width="150" CornerRadius="50,50,50,50" Margin="13,20,13,90">
                <Border.Background>
                    <ImageBrush x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="image1"    />
                </Border.Background>
            </Border>


            <TextBlock x:Name="txtreading" Height="30" Width="80" Margin="0,-145,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red"  FontSize="20" Text="ABC" TextAlignment="Center" />
            <!--<Image Height="120" Width="150" Margin="0,-50,0,0" Source="Assets/SmallLogo.scale-100.png" ></Image>-->
            <Path x:Name="MagnifyTip"  Data="m 422.67516,254.62099 c -54.00107,0 -97.94018,-42.99659 -97.94018,-95.82439 0,-52.83449 43.93911,-95.824384 97.94018,-95.824384 53.98741,0 97.93335,42.989894 97.93335,95.824384 0,52.8278 -43.94594,95.82439 -97.93335,95.82439 z m -4.5e-4,-201.388003 c -59.74605,0 -108.33864,48.616303 -108.33864,108.338643 0,56.09938 81.0924,116.80009 104.5378,191.74948 0.50401,1.61877 2.01605,2.72166 3.71189,2.7098 1.70178,-0.0237 3.1901,-1.13847 3.67039,-2.76909 C 449.00187,276.46834 531.00741,217.73624 531.01334,161.55977 531.00741,101.84929 482.4089,53.232987 422.67471,53.232987 Z" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" UseLayoutRounding="False" Height="227" Width="171" />


        </Grid>
    </Canvas>

</UserControl>
```

Please see the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Ie1Z-vk4aE&feature=youtu.be) here . When I tap on the screen the user control appears with some animation and disappears with some animation. If I tap and hold for some x sec(or ms) it and remove it , it goes off with some animation. I want the user control to appear in full shape in 0.04 seconds and disappear when I leave my finger. I need the similar kind of animation. No idea about it. Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 parts to this answer: 
1) creating the animation in Blend
and 
2) triggering the animation on tap

for 1) see here: http://www.kirupa.com/net/intro_blend_animation_pg3.htm This tutorial shows how to add simple animation for WPF in Blend, store apps animations can be added in a similar fashion.
For example, try to animate the Opacity a control over some time (e.g. 0.4s)
Here's the XAML I have:

```
   <Grid PointerPressed="Grid_PointerPressed" Background="Black">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Name="animFadeIn">
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.4" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="border" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <TextBlock Text="tap anywhere" FontSize="46" />
        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="109" Margin="463,310,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="158" Opacity="0" Background="White"/>
    </Grid>
```

for 2) you could trigger the animation from code behind on the PointerPressed event. Note I already have the handler in the XAML above.

```
  private void Grid_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        animFadeIn.Begin();
    }
```

Comment: I made it for my control ! but the problem is I am not getting what is implemented in the video ! I need exactly that

Comment: For that, you'll have to play some more with the animations - the animation in the video probably took quite a bit to implement, test, and improve.

Comment: Did u see that animation ? do you think that user control is a PNG image rather than path ?

Comment: Yes, saw it - I think it's likely a path.

Comment: What about it being a PNG image? Do you think we can make the user control with the PNG image and achieve the animation from it ?

Comment: I think it will be tough, because the animation changes the image significantly (not just stretching/rotating it)